# Iterating over JDBC Resultset object

Tags: java, database, jdbc

In a Java program I am using a complex query (a select clause which has inner joins and sub queries). I am iterating over the result set and writing output in a text file.

Select clause output can be of 400,000 records. Will it cause any issue if the result set has these many records? Does `ResultSet` has some record/memory limitations?

Comment: Which database are you using; result set behavior varies per database/driver and the result set concurrency used.

Comment: Do you need all 400,000 records? If not, narrow your selection in the `WHERE`-clause so as to only select the records you really need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ResultSet itself is unbound. Your JVM process and network capabilities have limitations though. If you need to process lots of records from one query try to play around with ResultSet options available:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement("select * from dual", ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
stmt.setFetchSize(1000);
```

Based on your database and/or driver vendor, those could help you process request faster with less memory footprint.

Comment: setting fetch size bigger is going to be faster but with MORE memory footprint.  It is simply a trade off between memory and DB round trips

Comment: @AdrianShum well, for some drivers this actually may trigger to split the requested data set into smaller pieces and send you them one by one instead of pushing the whole result set at once. But I agree with you, fetch size should be chosen wisely.

Comment: well, I cannot imagine in any case that setting to a **bigger** fetch size will make the driver split data in **smaller** pieces. The whole purpose for fetch size is to tell the driver to prepare buffer for retrieval for the provided number of records, it will not make sense if it turned out making it smaller.  And, it is simply a common sense that: if you fetch more things at once, you reduce roundtrips, but require more memory.  There is no way that making things smaller is going to reduce roundtrips.

Comment: Of course, if you compare a fetch size of enormous size vs fetch size of reasonably smaller size, the smaller size one may require less time but it is simply because the overhead caused by that enormous buffer causing the slowness.  And, setting to `1000` as in your example is rarely a reasonable number unless you are going to deal with extrememely huge number of records.  Normally the range for "big" fetch size is something around 20-100

Comment: @AdrianShum I didn't say bigger. If your set is  ~100000 records, split into 100 chunks by 1000 records is better than waiting for all records at once.

Comment: Yes, but it is the choice of fetch size causing the difference, but not "driver ... split ... in smaller piece" (because you are setting a bigger fetch size).  What I am trying to say: If you increase fetch size to improve performance, it is going to **increase** memory footprint, not making it smaller.

Comment: In case you dunno: you are actually setting it **BIGGER**.  JDBC's default fetch size is 5 or 10 (I forgot the exact figure).  i.e. If you are not setting it, it is slow NOT because it is waiting for all records, it is slow because everytime it is only fetching 5/10 records and there are lots of roundtrips

Comment: @AdrianShum isn't fetch size defaults is totally depend on a driver implementation? I'm actually not ready to argue on this topic while we still don't know the database vendor.

Comment: My fault here. please accept my apology.  Dunno why I keep on having a perception that OP is using Oracle... :P

Comment: Database i am working upon is 'Oracle' and App Server is Websphere.